# Unity C# importing local packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to do a simple import from a local path. Not sure where I'm messing up here. I'm not the strongest coder, so any insight is appreciated. Below is my attempt.

```
         [MenuItem("ImportMenu/ImportAsset")]
         static void ImportAssetOnlyImportsSingleAsset()
         {
             // My asset package file name
             string fileName = "MyAsset.unitypackage";
     
             // Project Asset folder path to save file to
             var assetsPath = Application.dataPath + "/" + fileName;
             Debug.Log($"Application.dataPath: {Application.dataPath}");
     
             // Where my asset package is located
             var filePath = "D:/Local_Projects/Packages/MyAsset";
             // Import asset
             AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(filePath);
     
             //Debug.Log("Imported: " + importedAssets);
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AssetDatabase` can only load from files from the root of the Project. These are Assets or Packages. If your project is not directly in `Local_Projects` it would not work.

From [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.ImportAsset.html)

> All paths are relative to the project folder, for example: "Assets/MyTextures/hello.png"

What you can do is copy the content of this package into the directory of the project.

```
File.Copy(fileToCopy, destinationFile); // or File.Move(...)
AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(destinationFile);
// Do something with this asset
// Optionaly
File.Remove(destinationFile);
```

Comment: Would that mean that I would have to unpack the files like a zip from the package first and then copy them to the project folder?  Thanks for the response btw!

Comment: AssetDatabase does not accept zip files. So yes, you need to unpack them first. But you can do this directly to the project folder, instead of copying them afterwards. You can also unzip them from the code if you wish (but this is outside of the scope of this question)

Comment: If this answer was helpful or resolved your issue please upvote and accept this as an answer! :)

Comment: This was helpful, thank you!